# Jquery: html, text and append functions are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple code to make requisition by ajax.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='jquery-2.2.4.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
      var url = "{{ url_for('ajaxPage') }}"; 
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $('form').serialize(), 
        dataType:'json',        
        success: function (data) {
                  var text= "Anything here!"; 
                  $('div.panel-body').html(text); //Not Working
                  $('div.panel-body').text(text); //Not Working
                  $('div.panel-body').append(text); //Not Working
                  alert(text); //Working
                  console.log(text); //Working

                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); 
        });

      }); 
  </script>
```

Here body layout:

```
<body>
  <div class="panel-body"> // Waiting content </div>
</body>
```

Ajax is working perfectly, I can view my array using console.log, alert, but I can not use **HTML(), TEXT() and APPEND()**. Where is my mistake? I already change JS file and I have other page with the same code and it works fine!

### Update

My Network page

[image]

**Updating body page**

```
<div class="input-group">
          <form method="POST" name='form'>
             <input type="text" name="inputxt" class="form-control" size="20">
           <button type="submit">Search</button>            
          </form>   
          </div>

<div class="panel-body">  

</div>
```

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: no, console is clear

Comment: do they work outside the Ajax function call?

Comment: An error is occuring.

Comment: @PerrinPrograms You mean, if the Ajax funtion is working properly? Yes!

Comment: @KevinB Where is occuring it?

Comment: Somewhere in your code or the server/network. Add an error handler.

Comment: @KevinB How I can view this error?

Comment: With the error handler.

Comment: The other possibility is that the code is in fact working, and you have a CSS problem.

Comment: @KevinB Where I can add the error handler?

Comment: Sidenote: if you are using Django, don't load static files with `url_for`, but rather with `static`

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde I'm using Flask

Comment: Then apologies. Just wanted to make sure :)

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde No problem, Any help would be most welcome!

Comment: Isolate further. Remove anything you dont need to add content to the page, until all you have is this: `$('.panel-body').html('hello');`  Once text starts appearing, add the other content back one line at a time and fix the bug.

Comment: console.log($('div.panel-body').length);

Answer (score 0):

I recreated this page and the problem was a css inside DIV.